# Can I create a custom Chart in Apache Superset?

Tags: apache-superset

I have been trying to customize Superset as much as possible and have succeeded to some extent. What I want to do now is create a custom chart based on my requirements, I have combined two big numbers to look like this using CSS properties but it's interfering with a lot of other properties of the charts in a given dashboard.
[image]

This is nothing but a set of two "big number" chart combined together with custom CSS. What I want to achieve is a customized widget having some special design or formatting. In simpler words to achieve the same below but with some word in between like:
30% Budget is providing me 70% output. Has anyone tried any hack to do that?

Comment: Recommend you to use the slack channel for particular code related discussions, in this case your big number chart. see project's README.md for slack channel links.

Answer (score 2):

as an update, recently Preset has released a [tutorial of just how to do that](https://preset.io/blog/2020-07-02-hello-world/). Basically with the new viz plugin architecture you can use any js library and do any customization you want, and integrate it to Superset. They also talked about the new architecture and did a live demo, [the video is here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6up5x_iRbI).

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Seems like it's supported on 0.37.0 and above versions. I tried to use it on 0.36.0 but had a lots of issues as mentioned here: https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/10352

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a custom chart in Superset.

You can follow some existing chart additions for example:
https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/pull/3013

to see how a new chart is developed and integrated in superset.